# Retrofit Not showing POJO response ,Showing only Raw Response in Android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

i am trying to get the Response from server using retrofit.

its showing only raw Response:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://********/GetData}
```

**Request code:**

```
Call<ResponsePOJO> call1 = apiInterface.sendField(requestPojo);
        call1.enqueue(new Callback<ResponsePOJO>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponsePOJO> call,Response<ResponsePOJO> response)
            {

                ResponsePOJO responsePOJO=response.body();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponsePOJO> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
            }
        });

@POST("/GetData")
   @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
   Call<ResponsePOJO> sendField(@Body RequestPojo requestPojo);
```

gradle file

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'

 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

**How to get json response?**

Comment: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://********/GetData} this one only :-(

Comment: @krishankTripathi json response is showing in logcat crtly

Comment: Please go through this tutorial https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-example/

Comment: can you show your whloe json response

Comment: {"ResponseHeader":{"MobileNo":"*****","ServiceCode":"RES","AppVersion":"1","ResponseCode":"0","ResponseDescription":""},"ResponseData":{"Data":""}}

Comment: @krishankTripathi check my Response

Comment: your response for Response hearder is not coming same So its recommended to not use pojo class used and other ways to access json value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169729/discussion-between-kumar-and-krishank-tripathi).